# PHP Dynamic drop down list for deleting rows

Tags: php

I am creating a deletion page for the removal of rows in the database. I have everything working up until the actual removal of the rows upon submit. The records display in the drop down without problem, any ideas of a solution are appreciated. (I am using deprecated SQL, I know.)

1ST PART OF PHP (FORM)

```
$query = 'SELECT event_name FROM event';
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        echo "<select name='events' value='-'>\n";
        echo "<option value='Select event'>Select an event to be deleted\n";

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result))
        {
        $eventSelect = $row[0];
        echo "<option value='$eventSelect'>$eventSelect</option>\n";
        }
        echo "</select>"
```

2ND PART OF PHP (DELETION)

```
    if (isset($_POST['eventSelect']))
{
$eventselection = $_POST['eventSelect'];

$query = "DELETE FROM event WHERE event_name = '$eventselection'";
$result = mysql_query($query);
}
```

Comment: share result of `var_dump($_POST)`. By the way `value` attribute should not be in `select` tag.

Comment: The name of your select is `events` not `eventSelect`

Comment: I hope this is not a production website, you have a big flaw of security

Comment: @MarkBaker Thank you, feel a bit stupid now

Comment: @jcho360 This is for a college project

Comment: I thought the same thing as Mark, yet the way it's setup with your `while` loop, wasn't entirely certain.

Comment: Making us `Feel Stupid` is nature's way of ensuring we don't make the same mistakes again